# how to remove white border using img tag

Tags: html, image, css

I can't find solution for this.

[image: Problem]

How to remove that white border around the triangle?

Code:

```
.triangle{
    background: url('/img/triangle.png');
    background-size: cover;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border: none;
}

<img class="triangle" />
```

Comment: if it's embedded on to the image, you can't... atleast not CSS... maybe with Adobe Photoshop

Comment: its not on the image. [here orginal](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Black_triangle.svg/2000px-Black_triangle.svg.png) it is without background

Comment: You're going to have to post more code (preferably all of it)... can't tell how you got the triangle on that image.

Comment: I didn't see any white border with this image go with this link may be it can help you https://jsfiddle.net/sqg0yt5z/13/ .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your markup isn't valid. The white border comes from your browsers *Image not found* visualization. To correct your markup, either set a `src` attribute to the image itself (it's mandatory, [see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)):

```
<img src="/img/triangle.png" />
```

or replace it by a div with the given background property, like this:

```css
.triangle {
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Black_triangle.svg/2000px-Black_triangle.svg.png');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your going to use the img tag for this task do

```
<img class="triangle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3c/Black_triangle.svg/2000px-Black_triangle.svg.png" />
```

it should fix your problem... Otherwise do exactly what did but make that img tag into a div.

Answer (score 0):

I would also look into "outline" and "outline-color" properties to either style it or make it disappear.

Here is more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline-color.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_outline.asp